# produccion.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, array, formularios, select, validación

He intentado validar este formulario, pero me es imposible ya que hay dos campos que debo validar por el nombre pero sus nombres son arrays **select name = "receta[]" y el input name="cantidad[]"** y no sé como validar estos campos.

Necesito validar todos los campos incluyendo el
**select name = "receta[]" y el input name="cantidad[]"**

Este es mi formulario

```
<form name="formulario" action="guardar_produccion.php" method="post">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-10" type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha">
    <select name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-10">
        <option>- Seleccione </option>
        <?php
        while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_usuario)) { //array recorre datos
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $datos['documento'] ?>"> <?php echo $datos['nombres'] ?> </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>



     <select  id="receta" name="receta[]" class="col-12 form-control mr-sm-2 "
                                             onchange="cambioOpciones1(), cambioOpciones()">
                                             <option value="" disabled selected> - Seleccione - </option>
                                             <?php

                                              while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_receta)) {
                                              ?>
                                                        <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>"
                                                         data-nombre="<?php echo $datos['producto'] ?>"
                                                         data-nombre1="<?php echo $datos['descripcion'] ?>">

                                                         <?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>  </option>
                                                          <?php } ?>
                                                          </select>

                 <input  id="cantidad" name="cantidad[]"  type="number"  min="1"  class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12"></input>

                 
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="CREAR ORDEN" id="boton">
</form>
```

Y tengo este código de validación

```
(function() {

    //acceder al formulario
    var formulario = document.getElementsByName("formulario")[0],
        elementos = formulario.elements, //se accede a los elementos  
        boton = document.getElementById("boton");

    var validarFecha = function(e) {

        if (formulario.fecha.value == '' || formulario.fecha.value == 0) {
            alert("Eliga una fecha de creación de la orden de producción.");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    };


    var validarUsuario = function(e) {
        if (!formulario.usuario.value) {
            alert("Que empleado esta a cargo de la orden  de producción?");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };

    var validarReceta = function(e) {
        // Se accede por nombre del campo, incluyendo los corchetes
        receta = formulario.querySelector('[name="receta[]"]');
        // Se analiza el valor, no el campo
        if (!receta.value) {
            alert("Complete el campo RECETA de creación.");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            console.log("Sí funciona, este es el valor: " + receta.value);
        }
    };


    var validarCantidad = function(e) {
        if (formulario.cantidad.value == 0) {
            alert("Debe elegir que cantidad de cada receta necesita ejecutar");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };


    var validar = function(e) {

        validarFecha(e);
        validarReceta(e);
        validarUsuario(e);
        validarCantidad(e);

    };

    formulario.addEventListener("submit", validar);
}())
```

El código de validación solo es funcional hasta el campo de la fecha y después de que valida ese campo sale este error en la consola

```
produccion.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at validarReceta (produccion.js:29)
    at HTMLFormElement.validar (produccion.js:49)
```

Sospecho que algo tiene que ver el nombre de ese select que es **receta[]** y no **receta**, pero esto no lo puedo cambiar ya que es necesario para otros asuntos del formulario.

Comment: Accede con `formulario.querySelector('[name="receta[]"]')`

Comment: @Triby Gracias, pero no funcionó, sin embargo edité la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dos cosas muy importantes:

1. Debes asignar `value=""` a las opciones por defecto, de lo contrario, el navegador te devolverá el texto de la opción.

```
<option disabled selected> - Seleccione - </option>
```

Cuando se evalúe, el valor será `- Seleccione -` y no `0` como esperas en `if (formulario.usuario.value == 0)`, entonces, debes asignar valor:

```
<option value="" disabled selected> - Seleccione - </option>
```

Para verificar el contenido, puedes aprovechar la característica de Javascript para analizar [valores tipo "falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (Cero, cadena vacía, entre otros), realizando la evaluación con:

```
if(!elemento.value) { console.log('Valor falsy'); }
```

2. Estás comparando el campo `if(formulario.querySelector('[name="receta[]"]') == 0)` porque omitiste `.value`, sabiendo que una cadena vacía se evalúa como falso, entonces podría quedar así: `if(!formulario.querySelector('[name="receta[]"]').value)`

Agregué un fragmento de código para que veas que sí funciona y, para dejar un poco más claro, separé obtener elemento y analizar valor del campo `receta[]`.

```js
(function() {

    //acceder al formulario
    var formulario = document.getElementsByName("formulario")[0],
        elementos = formulario.elements, //se accede a los elementos  
        boton = document.getElementById("boton");

    var validarFecha = function(e) {

        if (formulario.fecha.value == '' || formulario.fecha.value == 0) {
            alert("Eliga una fecha de creación de la orden de producción.");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    };


    var validarUsuario = function(e) {
        if (!formulario.usuario.value) {
            alert("Que empleado esta a cargo de la orden  de producción?");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };

       var validarReceta = function(e) {
           // Se accede por nombre del campo, incluyendo los corchetes
           receta = formulario.querySelector('[name="receta[]"]');
           // Se analiza el valor, no el campo
        if (!receta.value) {
            alert("Complete el campo RECETA de creación.");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            console.log("Sí funciona, este es el valor: " + receta.value);
        }
    };


    var validarCantidad = function(e) {
        if (formulario.cantidad.value == 0) {
            alert("Debe elegir que cantidad de cada receta necesita ejecutar");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };


    var validar = function(e) {

        validarFecha(e);
        validarReceta(e);
        validarUsuario(e);
        validarCantidad(e);

    };

    formulario.addEventListener("submit", validar);
}())
```

```html
<form name="formulario" action="guardar_produccion.php" method="post">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-10" type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha">
    <select name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-10">
        <option value="">- Seleccione </option>
        <option value="usuario1">Usuario 1</option>
        <option value="usuario2">Usuario 2</option>
        <option value="usuario3">Usuario 3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="receta" name="receta[]" class="col-12 form-control mr-sm-2 " onchange="cambioOpciones1(), cambioOpciones()">
        <option value="" disabled selected> - Seleccione - </option>
        <option value="codigo1" data-nombre="Nombre 1">codigo1</option>
        <option value="codigo2" data-nombre="Nombre 2">codigo1</option>
        <option value="codigo3" data-nombre="Nombre 3">codigo1</option>
    </select>
    <input id="cantidad" name="cantidad[]" type="number" min="1" class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="CREAR ORDEN" id="boton">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Sospecho que algo tiene que ver el nombre de ese select que es receta[] y no receta*

Pareciera que ese es tu problema, de ser así puedes intentar entonces:

```
var validarReceta = function(e) {
        if (formulario['receta[]'].value == 0 || formulario['receta[]'].value == "") {
            alert("Debe elegir  al menos una receta para ejecutar la orden  de producción");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Y si le integras un value a la opción bloqueada?

```
        <option disabled selected value=0> - Seleccione - </option>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo probé pero no hace ningún efecto

Answer (score 0):

Este error en específico siempre da cuando usted esta tratando de utilizar un valor de algo que es nulo o undefined. Intente lo siguiente y revise la consola para validar que todos los datos tengan un valor al menos vacío.
El siguiente código le va a ayudar a detectar cual es el dato o valor undefined que le esta provocando la excepción y a partir de ahí podrá realizar los ajustes necesarios (Solo modifique validarReceta pero puede hacer lo mismo en las demás funciones si fuera necesario):

```
    (function() {

    //acceder al formulario
    var formulario = document.getElementsByName("formulario")[0],
        elementos = formulario.elements, //se accede a los elementos  
        boton = document.getElementById("boton");

    var validarFecha = function(e) {

        if (formulario.fecha.value == '' || formulario.fecha.value == 0) {
            alert("Eliga una fecha de creación de la orden de producción.");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    };


    var validarUsuario = function(e) {
        if (formulario.usuario.value == 0) {
            alert("Que empleado esta a cargo de la orden  de producción?");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };

    var validarReceta = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            if (typeof(formulario)!=='undefined'&&typeof(formulario)!=='null') {
                console.log('formulario ok');
            }else{
                console.log('He aquí el culpable (formulario)');
            }
    
            if (typeof(formulario.cantidad)!=='undefined'&&typeof(formulario.cantidad)!=='null') {
                console.log('formulario.cantidad ok');
            }else{
                console.log('He aquí el culpable (formulario.cantidad)');
            }

            if (typeof(formulario.cantidad.value)!=='undefined'&&typeof(formulario.cantidad.value)!=='null') {
                console.log('formulario.cantidad.value ok');
            }else{
                console.log('He aquí el culpable (formulario.cantidad.value)');
            }


           
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };


    var validarCantidad = function(e) {
        if (formulario.cantidad.value == 0) {
            alert("Debe elegir que cantidad de cada receta necesita ejecutar");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };


    var validar = function(e) {

        validarFecha(e);
        validarReceta(e);
        validarUsuario(e);
        validarCantidad(e);

    };

    formulario.addEventListener("submit", validar);
}())
```

Comment: Gracias , parece que el error esta en  validar receta  sale esto en la consola ````formulario ok
produccion.js:37 He aquí el culpable (formulario.cantidad)
produccion.js:49 TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at validarReceta (produccion.js:40)
    at HTMLFormElement.validar (produccion.js:60)
produccion.js:62 Uncaught ReferenceError: validarCantidad is not defined
    at HTMLFormElement.validar (produccion.js:62)
validar @ produccion.js:62````